# Linear Algebra: Finding the basis of a subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $W=\{(v,w,x,y)\ |\ 0=2w-x+y+v\}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^4$

i) Show that $W$ is a subspace for $\mathbb{R}^4$

ii) If $W$ is a subspace, find the basis for $W$

I get how to do problems where we are given a set of vectors then asked to find if they are subspaces, but I'm stumped as to how I approach this question.

To show linear independence, do I have to show that that $(v,w,x,y)$ is not $(0,0,0,0)$?
To show that it spans $\mathbb{R}^4$, do I show that $k*(v,w,x,y) = B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (i), we know that $W$ is a nonempty subset of a known vector space.  Hence to prove it is a subspace it suffices to prove closure, i.e.

1. If $(v,w,x,y), (v',w',x',y')$ are both in $W$, then $(v,w,x,y)+(v',w',x',y')$ is in $W$.
2. If $(v,w,x,y)$ is in $W$, then for any scalar $k$, $k(v,w,x,y)$ is in $W$.

For (ii) your hint is that $W$ is three-dimensional, so a basis will be a set consisting of three linearly independent vectors from $W$.

Comment: Is W three dimensional because one of the variables is a linear combination of the other? So a to find a set of vectors that span W we just use the basic variables? and throw away one of the free variables (say, in this case x = 2w+y+v)?

Comment: @Dom, just as you say.

Comment: You've been a great help, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so I believe that you might not have the correct definition of a vector subspace.

Start here: A subset $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace if:

1. for every $v, w \in W$, $v+w \in W$.
2. for every $v \in W$, $\lambda \cdot v \in W$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

so start by showing that the $W$ that you have defined above satisfies (1) and (2). This will show that $W$ is a subspace.

Now to find a basis for $W$, you can do several things. My suggestion would be to think of the following fact:

if $v = (w,x,y,z) \in W$ then it follows that $v\cdot (2,-1,1,1) = 2w-x+y+u = 0$. That is: every $v \in W$ is orthogonal to $(2,-1,1,1) $. Hence, to find a basis for this space, you need to find three linearly independent vectors which are all orthogonal to $(2,-1,1,1) $. I should mention that this doesn't show that the vectors you find actually span $W$. You also need to show this.

Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: I understand proving the subspace, what I'm having trouble is the basis.

Comment: Try using a technique from solving systems of equations: that is set 2w - x + y +u = 0, and then write: w = 1/2(x-y-u). x = x, y = y, u = u. and rewrite this in terms of a vector.

Comment: I see my error now, my mistake was that I assumed I had to show that the vector (v,w,x,y) spanned W and was linearly independent (which didn't make any sense, hence why I was confused), instead of finding a combination of vectors that that formed the basis for W.